# Is there a tool to count the latency of UDP datagrams in Linux?

Tags: networking, udp, benchmark

Now I want to test the network performance between two Linux systems.

The test scenario is as follows: one terminal sends UDP datagrams to the other terminal continuously at fixed intervals (the interval and the length of the datagram are defined by the user), and finally I can get the latency required for each UDP message to reach the receiving end, as well as their maximum, minimum and average latency.

I would like to know if there is any such tool in Linux that can meet my needs?

Comment: `iperf` (version 2, not 3) has some support for that.

Comment: Also [`netperf`](https://github.com/HewlettPackard/netperf).

Answer (score 2):

The following programs are network monitoring tools able to measure throughput and other data, with support for UDP:

- `iptraf`
- `iperf`
- `netperf`/`netserver`